# Calculating different means in a single loop

Tags: loops, mean

So I have different lists, each containing 3 numbers, and I need to calculate the means of each list.

I have tried with:

```
print(statistics.mean(single list))
```

But I don't know how to make a loop taking in each list, containing the 3 numbers, calculating each mean.

The list are like:

```
A: 10.1, 10.4, 10.3

B: 11.2, 11, 10.8

and so on...
```

Is it possible to create a loop which calculates each mean and provides me with a list of each mean from the different lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List comprehension is your friend:

```
means_array = [statistics.mean(single_list) for single_list in multiple_lists]
print(means_array)
```

Where multiple_lists is [A, B...]

Edit: You can also look into Numpy library, it will allow you to do it even easier:

```
numpy.mean([A, B...], axis=1)
```

Will return list of means.